# invalid dsn: invalid connection option "postgis_extension"

Tags: python, django, postgresql, geolocation, postgis

On localhost everything is working fine. But I am having problems with https://rossdjangoapp.herokuapp.com/.

[image]

I tried to follow this tutorial https://medium.com/the-geospatials/deploy-geodjango-application-to-heroku-in-2019-part-3-41ca4535f377.

I got the below error messages.

```
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://github.com/peterkeen/heroku-buildpack-


remote:  !     The GDAL, GEOS and PROJ binaries and BUILD_WITH_GEO_LIBRARIES functonality are now deprecated.
remote:  !     An alternative buildpack to enable GDAL, GEOS and PROJ use is available here - https://github.com/heroku/heroku-geo-buildpack


remote:        ### WARNING: THIS BUILDPACK HAS BEEN DEPRECATED
remote:        Please check https://git.io/fj5QW
```

These are the build packs I now have.

[image]

I want to add map functionality to my site.

[image]

**settings.py**

```
import os


if os.name == 'nt':
    import platform
    OSGEO4W = r"C:\OSGeo4W"
    if '64' in platform.architecture()[0]:
        OSGEO4W += "64"
    assert os.path.isdir(OSGEO4W), "Directory does not exist: " + OSGEO4W
    os.environ['OSGEO4W_ROOT'] = OSGEO4W
    os.environ['GDAL_DATA'] = OSGEO4W + r"\share\gdal"
    os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = OSGEO4W + r"\share\proj"
    os.environ['PATH'] = OSGEO4W + r"\bin;" + os.environ['PATH']
    GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = r'C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\gdal300.dll'
import django_heroku


BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))



SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')

DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['rossdjangoawesomeapp.herokuapp.com', 'localhost', '127.0.0.1', 'localhost:8000']

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'blog.apps.BlogConfig',
    'users.apps.UsersConfig',
    'crispy_forms',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    'django_comments',
    'shops',
    'django.contrib.gis'
]

SITE_ID = 1

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    ]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'django_project3.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]


WSGI_APPLICATION = 'django_project3.wsgi.application'





DATABASES = {

    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis',
        'NAME': 'postgres',
        'USER': 'postgres',
        'PASSWORD': 'Albertros577015',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '5432'
    }


}


AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]



LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'blog-home'
LOGIN_URL = 'login'

EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD =  os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASS')
EMAIL_PORT = 587

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (

    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',


    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
    )

CRISPY_TEMPLATE_PACK = 'bootstrap4'

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = os.environ.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = os.environ.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = os.environ.get('AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME')




AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

**It is now working**

I looked at Adems answer ([Running PostGIS with Django on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49969950/running-postgis-with-django-on-heroku/59323972#59323972)). And also had to go to https://data.heroku.com/, click on Settings and look at the Database credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the external  import in the settings.py file,for example the heroku import and remove the django_heroku.settings(locals()) but only leave the AWS settings,then run again

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I have now updated my original question with the solution I used in the end.